# Instalar, xampp, heidi, composer en el disco duro hdd y usarlos desde ubuntu en el disco ssd?

Tags: php, ubuntu

De que manera correcta me recomendarian usar esta combinacion. Tengo una ssd y quiero darle el mejor rendimiento a mi maquina. En la ssd deberia instalar el sistema operativo y el hdd instalar todos los programas que voy a usar? O deberia instalar esos programas para trabajar en la misma ssd donde instale el sistema operativo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estos programas son lo bastante ligeros para trabajar conjuntamente con el sistema operativo Ubuntu que mencionas en un mismo SSD, por muy pequeño que sea, lo que te recomiendo es que instales todo en el disco duro del sistema, ya que instalar paquetes de software en Linux en discos externos puede conllevar problemas a la larga.

Reserva el HDD para el almacenamiento de archivos mas pesados y que no vayan a comprometer la correcta funcionalidad de los servicios que deseas instalar de tu maquina.

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias amigo por el aporte